# fade image when you hover text

Tags: css, image, text, hover, fade

You do not know how to write a function so that when you hover on the picture or text, fade the image.
http://jsfiddle.net/Tiimsvk/8mwh03fr/

```html
<script>
function showimg1(img){
    obr=document.getElementById('showingimg1');
    obr.src=img;
    return false;
}
</script>
<a href="#"><img src="http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003D.jpg" onmouseover="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003C.jpg');" onmouseout="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003D.jpg');" id="showingimg1"></a> 
 <a href="#" onmouseover="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003C.jpg');" onmouseout="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003D.jpg');">RODINNÉ DOMY</a>
```

Comment: do it with CSS not JS...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
function showimg1(img){
    obr=document.getElementById('showingimg1');
    obr.src=img;
    return false;
}
</script>
<style>
    #image{
//define all of the transitions, to make the animation smooth
-webkit-transition:1s;
-moz-transition:1s;
transition:1s;
}

#image:hover{

opacity:0.8; // fade the opacity to a subtle lower value

    }
</style>
<a href="#"><img class="image" src="http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003D.jpg" onmouseover="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003C.jpg');" onmouseout="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003D.jpg');" id="showingimg1"></a> 
 <a href="#" onmouseover="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003C.jpg');" onmouseout="return showimg1('http://lumainterier.eu/image/interier/schodiska/scale/003D.jpg');">RODINNÉ DOMY</a>
```

does not fade the picture when I go through the text or image